How to handle door casing close to a wall corner when wall is not parallel with door frame?
To the right of my door frame is a nearby wall corner that is out of plumb.  The wall diverges from the door frame by ~3/4" from the bottom to the top - the corner of the wall is 3.5" from the frame at the bottom and 4.25" at the top.
If the wall corner was farther away from my door, this wouldn't be an issue - the eye wouldn't really notice the difference.  In this case, however, it's pretty obvious, and I'm wondering if anyone has any clever suggestions about how to approach the problem.
For what it's worth, the door casing I am planning to install is a simple homemade approach - it's 2.5" wide board with 1" backbanding, for a total of 3.5" wide.
Here is the bottom part of the door:

And here is the top of it:

A few options I have considered:
A) Just install the casing more or less as shown.  In this case, it touches the wall corner at the bottom of the door and has a 3/4" gap at the top.  The long, skinny triangle/wedge created is not ideal visually (or to paint in the future).
B) Create narrower casing.  This doesn't avoid the long, skinny triangle - it just makes it a little larger and (maybe?) not quite as noticeable.
C) Create casing that is narrower at the bottom and wider at the top.  Perhaps this would do the best job at tricking the casual eye into thinking everything is normal?  Either that or it's going to look like a crazy fun-house...
I am inexperienced with this - any suggestions from those of you who may have encountered this before?  (and please feel free to move to diy.stackexchange if that is more appropriate - I am not sure)

This is obviously one of those situations where there's no ideal solution..... barring remaking the corner itself :-D so it really just becomes a matter of picking the compromise that you're most comfortable with. I've lived with, and seen many more, door frames that paid no respect to the nearest corner/jink in the plasterwork because of how common this sort of thing is, especially in older homes over here — it's by no means a new-build phenomenon (and don't even get me started on Georgian homes OMG!)

My inclination would be to try option C first, and see what you think. 3/4 is a lot, though, so you might have to do A.
